# PHP count value in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code like this:

```
<?php if(isset($global_info_results)): ?>
   <?php echo count($global_info_results) ?>
   <span>Mali Oglasi: </span>
   <?php foreach ($global_info_results as $result) : ?>
      <?php if($result->info_type_id == 1) : ?>
         <p><?php echo $result->name?></p>
      <?php endif ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

How can I count specific value inside array (for example I want to count how much result have `info_type_id  == 1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <?php $a = 0
   foreach ($global_info_results as $result)
    if($result->info_type_id == 1)
      { $a = $a + 1}
     End Foreach?>

  <span>Mali Oglasi: </span>
  <?php foreach ($global_info_results as $result) : ?>
      <?php if($result->info_type_id == 1) : ?>
         <p><?php echo $result->name?></p>
```

Comment: I need to count before title (Mali Oglasi: )

Answer (score 3):

You could use [array_filter](http://uk.php.net/array_filter) to generate an array of values that match the criteria you want a count of and then run count on the result.  The below example returns the number of elements in an array that have a value greater than 4:

```
$items = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$itemsOfInterest = array_filter ($items, function ($elem) {return ((int) $elem > 4);})
echo (count ($itemsOfInterest));
```

Comment: It does require PHP 5.3+, otherwise you'll have to define the callback separately and provide its name as the callback argument.