# Loop Array to Find Results in a Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file which I have converted to an array using PHP which looks something similar to this but with a lot more records:

```
Array(
 [0] = > Array
 {
   [firstName] = > John
   [surname] = > Smith
 }

 [1] => Array
 {
   [firstName] = > David
   [surname] = > Jones
 }
)
```

I'm looking to take this array of data and perhaps loop through it to find the records in my database that match the data in the array. I'm new to PHP and using this data to query a database. Any guidance will be appreciated!

If you need the code that I used to convert the CSV to an array then let me know and I'll edit the question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You don't know how to query the database? You don't know how to loop through an array? You don't know what query to use?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't know how to use the data I have in the array to query the database

Answer (score 0):

if you want search a value in array you can use `in_array` function

if you have a 2d array and want search a value use `foreach` loop and `in_array`

```
foreach($mother_arr as $child_arr){
    if(in_array($value,$child_arr)){
        echo "match"
        break;
    }
}
```

if you want search array in array you can use this function ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909826/php-search-array-in-array))

```
function searchMyCoolArray($arrays, $key, $search) {
   foreach($arrays as $object) {
       if(is_object($object)) {
          $object = get_object_vars($object);
       }
       if(array_key_exists($key, $object) && $object[$key] == $search){
           echo "match";
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I was looking for... I want to use the data in my array to search for records in my database e.g. place the data into a query or something like that. Thanks for replying though! This answer might help someone

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how you connect to the DB, here is an example for PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    select 1
    from users
    where firstname = :firstName
      and surname   = :surname
    limit 1
');

foreach ($csvData as $key => $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
    $csvData[$key]['exists'] = ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 1);
}
```

This will add to every element of your array a new boolean field `exists`, which will be `true` if the row already exists in the `users` table.